# comandline function not working in .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command

I had a problem and wanted to share it because I was not able to find a answer here.

I needed a script which will list the directory tree and output it to an .txt-file.

```
tree <path> /f /a > output.txt
```

After I had working code which I was able to execute correct directly in the commandline I pasted it into a tree.bat and saved it in the folder which I wanted to explore.

**Solution:
The path was pointing to the same directory where the tree.bat was placed. Instead of calling the function "tree" it was calling the tree.bat and I had a loop.**
The output.txt was not clear, so it took a while to figure out what went wrong.

I hope it helps someone else who is having similar errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved by doing in your batch file:

```
set Target_PATH=%~dp0
cd %Target_PATH%
tree <path> /f /a > output.txt
```

By default batch executes in your machine from path which you get by doing

```
echo %CD%
```

The first two lines set the path to the path of location of your batch file before executing the tree command.

Please let me know if you get stuck or have further queries.

Comment: @code_frenzy Unfortunately that does not work for me.
It still executes the tree.bat instead of the tree command.
**The same code works fine when I name the .bat-file mytree.bat or something different from tree.**

But the %CD% command works great as I was going to analyse the folder in which the .bat was placed. Thanks a lot for that.